# Why does my class not implement its properties?

Tags: c#, .net, class, properties, null

I have a class named Restaurant:

```
namespace Futures.Api.Data.Models
{
    public class Restaurant
    {
        public Restaurant()
        {
            Dishes = new HashSet<Dish>();
        }
    
        [Display(Name = "Restaurant Id")]
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int RestaurantId { get; set; } 
    
        [Display(Name = "Restaurant Name")]
        public string RestaurantName { get; set; } = null!;
    
        [Display(Name = "Category Name")]
        public string CategoryName { get; set; } = null!;
    
        [Display(Name = "Restaurant Address")]
        public string RestaurantAddress { get; set; } = null!;
    
        [Display(Name = "Zone Id")]
        public int? ZoneId { get; set; }
    
        public virtual FoodCategory CategoryNameNavigation { get; set; } = null!;
        public virtual Zone? Zone { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Dish> Dishes { get; set; }
        public virtual Dish Dish { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And I have XUnit Test Class within which I am instantiating the class restaurant like so

```
Restaurant restaurant1 = new Restaurant
{
    RestaurantName = "Khana",
    RestaurantAddress = "Tokyo",
    CategoryName = "Indian",
    ZoneId = 2
};
```

And yet when I try to catch the name with the below method it returns a null exception, see below method

```
[Fact]
public async Task GetRestaurantByName()
{
    Restaurant restaurant = await _repository.GetByName("Khana");

    Assert.Equal("Khana", restaurant.RestaurantName);
}
```

See error 'System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

When running the debug I see that restaurant1 doesn't contain the name or any other properties, apart from the 'CategoryNameNavigation', see below screenshot

[image: screenshot debugger]

Or here the autos

```
  restaurant    CategoryNameNavigation = null   
  Futures.Api.Data.Models.Restaurant

   CategoryNameNavigation   null    

   Futures.Api.Data.Models.FoodCategory
   +        this
```

{Futures.Api.Data.Sqlite.Test2.SqliteRestaurantTest.FuturesConfigTests}
Futures.Api.Data.Sqlite.Test2.SqliteRestaurantTest.TestWithSqlite

{Futures.Api.Data.Sqlite.Test2.SqliteRestaurantTest.FuturesConfigTests}

As  you can see, all the properties (such as RestaurantName) are gone :(

Here is the method GetByName

```
    public async Task<Restaurant?> GetByName(string restaurantName)
    {
        return await _context.Restaurants
            .Include(restaurantRecord => restaurantRecord.Dishes)
            .Include(restaurantRecord => restaurantRecord.Zone)
            .Include(restaurantRecord => restaurantRecord.CategoryNameNavigation)
            .SingleOrDefaultAsync(record => record.RestaurantName.ToLower().Contains(restaurantName.ToLower()));
    }
```

I would be grateful if anyone could hint me to where the issue here, any tips are welcome!

Being quite a newbie to c# I am sure there's something obvious I missed here.

Comment: I think your Method `_repository.GetByName("Royal Motimahal")` is broken and does not return any result

Comment: Could you share the method under test "_repository.GetByName" ?

Comment: You need to figure out if `restaurant` is null (which is probably the case) or the Property. Since you get a NRE, I'd guess it's the former. That in turn means that the method under test is broken. So you need to look at that one. Your Class looks fine.

Comment: Thanks for the answers! I have added the method GetByName.

Comment: Indeed restaurant comes as null here. Checking the method as it is probably where the issues lies

Comment: do you have a key?

Comment: Hi Gauravsa, thanks for asking, the [key] here is from Entity Framework, it's used as the primary key in the dabatase - see article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/keys?tabs=data-annotations

Comment: Where is your  ``restaurant1`` persisted? You've created an instance of it in the test class; how should your ``_repository.GetByName(string)`` method find it if it is only an instance in the test class?

Comment: Double check the linq statemenet Contains, I dont think this always work as you expect.  I would step through and maybe just try something like firstordefault to see if you can get any result to return from that method for now.  Then make the changes accordingly.